# Why is docker extension is not working in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get the following error message on vs code regarding the docker extension:

> "Cannot activate the 'Docker' extension because it depends on an unknown 'vs code.docker' extension"

vs code is the latest version and the Docker extension is from Microsoft